# KSH script out put spacing issue

Tags: linux, database, unix, ksh, metrics

I am writing KSH script to read / print data to a file, when the file is printed out the spacing is not quit right, anyway here is the partial script:

```
movieList(){
if[[ -s ${2} ]
then
    echo -n -e "${work_around}\t" >> movieList_${work_around}
    echo -n -e 'cat ${2} | grep 'UID' | sed 's/:/,/' | awk -F'|' '{print $3}'`' >>movieList_${work_around}
    ...
    echo -n -e 'cat ${2} | grep 'movie_started' | sed 's/:/,/' | awk -F'|' '{print $3}'`' >>movieList_${work_around}
    ...
```

so the example output is:

```
324, Black swan, Natalie Portman, 2010
 654, Black swan, Mila Kunis,2010
```

this is what I want to happen:

```
 324, Black swan, Natalie Portman, 2010
 654, Black swan, Mila Kunis,      2010
```

The example output data is not the actual data due to the data sensitivity, but basically that would demonstrate the spacing issue that I am having, the data is not aligned for some reason. It doesn't happen to all the data output but to some data, the space seems off a little as you see, it is not aligned.
Please help..
Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Use `printf` and specify the field width in the formatting operator.

Comment: Okay, I will try that out and update the result here tomorrow. Thank you!